# Error with backquotes when import parser from dateutil with Python3.5

Tags: python, parsing, tensorflow, python-module

I used Tensorflow. It was working.
After I installed Caffe (with all dependencies) my old TF projects stopped working.

The root cause is:

```
from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
```

gives

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /data/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/test/test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/test/test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 158
    l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

as a result

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

doesn't work because of dependencies

Why is it happened? It was working before Caffe installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that installing your Caffe updated Python? A L-O-O-N-G time ago Python used backticks as a shortcut for calling the `repr` function on its argument. Replacing the backtick-quoted expression with `repr(value)` might be all you need.

Comment: Python is not updated. I'm not sure that I can manually replace all occurrences in third-party libraries.

Comment: Your libraries are clearly very old. Aren't updated copies available?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the prompt about "L-O-O-N-G time ago".
Updated libraries.
Works.